# What is the function of scope resolution operator in class name in the class definition?

Tags: c++

How to Interpret the name of class in following piece of C++ code ?

Following code is part of a project which is compiling successfully with g++ compiler.

```
class ABC::DEF
{
   public :
      int a;
      void func();
};

void ABC::DEF::func() { a = 3; } 

ABC::ABC() : OBJ(new DEF())    
{
}
ABC::~ABC()
{
  delete OBJ;
}
```

- How to interpret ABC,DEF and OBJ in the above code?
- How the constructor defined above works ?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How to interpret the class name here - string::string ?

Comment: The code above does not compile on C++ compiler and there are no C++ interpreters.

Comment: It would sound quite well on a piano, but you could interpret it as a rock ballad as well... for C++, it's rubbish.

Comment: Is this a completely invalid code in C++, I saw it in a project which is successfully compiling with g++.

Comment: It means there's a class called `ABC`, which contains a nested class called `DEF`. Look in the definition of `ABC` and you should see the declaration `class DEF;`. This is the definition of that class.

Comment: @ÖöTiib [There](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling) are [C++ interpreters](https://www.softintegration.com/)

Comment: So , I guess its not rubbish for C++ !

Comment: @ted: No, it's not rubbish. See the answer below.

Comment: Should i flag question my question to re open, I tried to make it clear as i can, Or put it as it is now (closed) as I got my answer already ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `ABC` most likely looks something like this:

```
class ABC
{
public:
    ABC();
    ~ABC();

private:        
    class DEF;
    DEF* OBJ;
};
```

and what you're looking at is the definition of the class `ABC::DEF` and the constructors of `ABC`.

(This is a quite normal way of implementing the "pimpl idiom".)

Comment: I tried the above definition and it compiled successfully in codepad.  
http://codepad.org/ujklAo5I
So I guess to use the member function declared in the DEF class we need to define member functions for ABC class and call DEF methods with the OBJ pointer ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ABC::DEF is a nested class. If you look at the definition for class ABC, you should see a forward declaration of class DEF. You can give the full definition for such a class outside of the outer class as shown in your question.